# he first isomorphism theorem to deduce that G/K ⇠= H.

Tags: abstract-algebra

For an abelian group $G$, consider the sets $H = \{g^2 | g\in G\}$ and $K = \{g\in G | g^2 = e\}$.

$f : G \to G$ defined by $f(g) = g^2$ is a homomorphism.

use the first isomorphism theorem to deduce that G/K ⇠= H.

i'm stuck here. i know i have to use the isomorphism theorem but i can't simply start the question.

Comment: What does the theorem say? What objects in the theorem could correspond to the objects in your question?

Comment: it says 'The image of φ is isomorphic to the quotient group G / ker(φ)'

Comment: And so what could you take to be $\varphi$ here then?

Comment: In other words: What is the only thing mentioned inthe problem statement taht is a homomorphism? What is its image? What is its kernel?

Comment: thats G/K ⇠= H.

Answer (score 0):

The first isomorphism theorem will tell you that $G/Kerf\cong Imf$. So, what you want to prove is that $H\cong Imf$ and that $K \cong Kerf$, and then you will get that $G/K\cong H$, as needed. But notice that:
$$H=\{g^2 | G\in G\} = \{f(g) | g\in G\} = Imf$$
$$K= \{g\in G | g^2 = e\} = \{g\in G | f(g) = e\} = Ker(f)$$
So you get what you need.

Comment: so i deduce from the first isomorphism theorem  that G/K ⇠= H

Comment: since it says The image of f is isomorphic to the quotient group G / ker(f)

Comment: Exactly - H is exactly the image of f and K is exactly the kernel, so that's what you get.